# How do I supply the path to a Rails application despite being in the root folder?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, brakeman

I am trying to run Brakeman on my code to identify any security vulnerabilities.

I have installed the gem and I am in the root folder of my Rails 4.2.4 application.

However when I try and run Brakeman using:

```
brakeman –f html -o brakeman.html
```

I keep getting the following message returned in the terminal:

> Please supply the path to a Rails application.

How is this done in a Rails environment for this gem?

Comment: Perhaps you should show us the list of files and directories in your current directory.

Comment: thanks for the note. What specific files would be useful to show.

Comment: Not the contents, just the list. `ls`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can additionally supply the root like so :

```
brakeman . –f html -o brakeman.html
```

Albeit, it's strange it's not auto-detecting that. Perhaps because of all the options you chose. I'd also try stripping it down as just performing :

```
brakeman
```

.. and see if that can detect that you're in the root.

Comment: thank you. When i used the one word brakeman command the whole thing executed which is great and I can now see the scan report. thanks for your help sir.

Answer (score 1):

The options you supplied should work just fine, although `-f html` is redundant when the extension of the output file is `.html`.

The real root of the issue is using `–f` (en dash) instead of `-f` (hyphen). Subtle difference; perhaps due to copy-pasting the command.